# Best way to store a list in a single SQL cell

Tags: sql

So I have multiple tables for a railway system

- `Station` (StationID, ...)
- `Route` (RouteID, StartStationID, TerminalStationID, ...)
- `Stops` (StopID, RouteID, {StationStops}, ...)

I want a way to store `StationID` as a list in `Stops(StationStops)` depending on the number of stops.

So if I have a route: `Route(1, 5, 9, ...)`

then I would want to store the number of stops for that route as:

```
Stops(1, 1, {6,7,8})
```

Bearing in mind `{6,7,8}` would be other `StationID`s

What would be the best way of achieving this? The only thing I can think of is store it as a list but how do I do that?

Comment: Many-Many relational table is the right way to do with SQL

Answer (score 1):

Use *many-many* relationship table between routes and stations.

Each route may have multiple stations and every train on routes may stop on multiple stations.

https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/18/fmp/en/index.html#page/FMP_Help/many-to-many-relationships.html